# Request::getQueryString() without some parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-request

I am using the following code to append the query strings with two links. But I want to exclude the page parameter of pagination from the query string.

```
<li><a href="/teachers?{{ Request::getQueryString()}}">Teachers</a></li>

<li><a href="/courses?{{ Request::getQueryString()}}">Courses</a></li>
```

What is the way to do it? I tried the following code but it generates error.

```
<li><a href="/teachers?{{ Request::getQueryString()->except('page') }}">Teachers</a></li>

<li><a href="/courses?{{ Request::getQueryString()->except('page') }}">Courses</a></li>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well `getQueryString()` just returns a string. Instead you can use `Request::except()` directly and then call [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate the query string:

```
<li><a href="/teachers?{{ http_build_query(Request::except('page')) }}">Teachers</a></li>
```

Note that if you have POST values, those will be included too. If you want to avoid that do this:

```
<li><a href="/teachers?{{ http_build_query(array_except(Request::query(), 'page')) }}">Teachers</a></li>
```

Comment: It is giving error.. Call to undefined function http_build_str()

Comment: Sorry it's actually `http_build_query()`